# mysql find_in_set matching 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a query working find_in_set working like this

```
$groupid = 245;
$formsidlist = '52,57,103,104,105,107,109,110';
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__immi_visaformfields WHERE 
FIND_IN_SET('$groupid','field_duplicate')  AND published='1' AND 
 FIND_IN_SET(formid,'$formsidlist') ORDER BY id";
```

Now I have formsidlist changed to

```
$formsidlist = '52-1,57-2,103-1,104-1,105-2,107-1,109-1,110-1';
```

and from 52-1, 52 should be compared to formid column and 1 should be compared to formversionid column.

How do I acheive this?

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. So with `'published'='1'` you are asking whether the string `'published'` equals the string `'1'`, which is never true. Does your query even return any row? It shouldn't. Make this `published = '1' ` instead, if you want to compare with a column called `published`.

Comment: Yes @ThorstenKettner made that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate formid with '-' and formversionid:

```
FIND_IN_SET(concat(formid, '-', formversionid), '$formsidlist') ORDER BY id";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Please go through my question again, 52 should be compared to formid column and 1 should be compared to formversionid column

Comment: Ah, sorry. The answer is the same though: concatenate. I've updated my answer.